# Check if variable exist or not

Tags: javascript, jira

I'm using API Jira
I'm doing some functions but before to use function, I need to verified if a value exist or not

If he exists so I can launch functions else do nothing.

I'm doing this :

```
    // Call the file functions.js
var functions = require('./functions.js')




/* 
Function getAllIssueForSCII displays all the issues in the form of a JSON and that browses all the keys that are in the SCII project
Function pushInitialization initializes the computer score card to 80 on Jira

*/

functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(function(json){
    for (let i=0; i<json.issues.length;i++){
        if(json.issues[i].fields.customfield_14038 = null){     // i'm doing this
        console.log(json.issues[i].key);
        functions.pushInitialization(json.issues[i].key);
    }
}
});

/* 
A delay is added so that Jira can correctly recover the value 80.
Thanks to this value, we can do all the calculation  (Function calculate)  
Function pushComputerScoreCard  push the final value into the computer score card.
Function generateJSON generates a JSON.
Function replaceCharacter solve the problem of array inside the JSON 
*/

setTimeout(function() {
    functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(function(json){
        for (let i=0; i<json.issues.length;i++){
            functions.calculate(json.issues[i]);
            functions.pushComputerScoreCard(json.issues[i].key);
            functions.generateJSON(json.issues[i].key);
            functions.replaceCharacter();

        }

    });
}, 1000)
```

My problem: After the settimeout, he recover value already exist and do the calcul...

I need to verified my condition in all of the script .

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning null value in an if condition:

```
if(json.issues[i].fields.customfield_14038 = null){     // i'm doing this
```

You need to compare values:

```
if(json.issues[i].fields.customfield_14038 === null){     // You need to do this:
```

Comment: Oh I put "===" in my original script, I don't know why I write only "=" here ...
My problem is after the setTimeout I thing